# CDATA to ignore html tags doesn't work

Tags: xml, parsing, cdata

Hi I'm passing a message to an attribute in XML. The xml is 'emailBodyXML' and the attribute I want to receive the message is the 'body'. The message I'm passing is contained in a variable 'emailBody'.

I have this code:

```
emailBodyXML.selectSingleNode("//email").setAttribute("body", "<![CDATA[" + emailBody + "]]>");
```

I put cdata in it because I want it to ignore the html tags the emailBody may contain.
But when I debug it, the html tags get converted to `&lt;` or `&gt;`. I don't like it to get converted to that. I want it to still show '<' and '>'. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `<` in an attribute value, so your `<![CDATA[`... is invalid. You aren't going to be able to put markup in a attribute value without using entities for `<` (and quotes, ampersands, etc.). Your best bet would be to use `CDATA` in an element instead.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#attdecls

Example:

```
<body><![CDATA[<p>HTML MARKUP GOES HERE.</p>]]></body>
```

Comment: I googled and most of my searches say using CDATA on an element is not possible. How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: Hi thanks. so if I can't CDATA an attribute, I used CDATA on the text.So this is what I did,the xml looked like this, <email><body>TEXT VALUE</body></email>. instead of what i did above to pass the value of the 'emailBody' to the attribute 'body', I just passed it to its text(TEXT VALUE) so that I can CDATA it: 

emailBodyXML.selectSingleNode("//email/body").text = "<![CDATA[" + emailBody + "]]>";

it still won't work. do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is now *obsolete* for HTML.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection#Specifications says:

> Note that CDATA sections should not be used within HTML; they only
>   work in XML.

See also